# Loss precision of double stored to numeric in postgres via jpa entity manager

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

While saving java `Double` to posgres `numeric` type. The value `4.324325500000001` stored as `4.3243255`. Entity manager used for this purpose.

```
public class Amount {
    private UUID uuid;
    private Double value;
}

entityManager.merge(amount);
```

If update is done by direct sql query there is no such a problem.

```
update t.amount
set value=4.324325500000001
where uuid='7981cdea-f1a7-4374-9795-da86561902c1';
```

What is the way to setup default precision for all jpa transactions (not for just one column)? Is it possible to set hibernate option or spring properties?
Using a `BigDecimal` is not option cause backward compatibility.

Comment: What's the definition of the column in the DB?

Comment: `create table t.amount (amount numeric, ins_itm_uuid uuid  not null}` 
Like that

Comment: It could be a couple of things:  1) maybe the column in your database isn't setup to use that much precision.  Try setting values manually in DB to verify.  2) It could be a simple precision error in the the JVM.  Sometimes with very high precision value can be lost.

Comment: 1. Can you log the update statement created by JPA? 2. First example is misleading, you should pass an entity, not a double to EntityManager. What is the field type in the entity? My guess is that you used a `float`.

Comment: In the log I see the question marks instead of values, but when I'm debugging before the merge the value in entity is sharp.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your info with an Entity you can try to specify the precision and the scale.

Ex:
`@Column(precision=8, scale=2) Double amount;`

Here precision is for the number you want to after the comma and scale is how many scale you want to see.

So 4.3243200000001 will have a precision of 15.

Comment: Yes, but could I set this precision globally, not for just one column? Because it should be a common behaviour.

Comment: I don't think because it's not an hibernate parameter, it's column specific.
See : [link](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Column.html)